# Use year as label for monthly data histogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, axis, grids

I have data in the format `year`,`month` and `amount`. I want to illustrate this data using a histogram. Since the data covers multiple years, printing the months just stacks everything. I try to use the years as labels and a year dividing grid instead.

Current solution:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width=1.1\textwidth,
    height=\axisdefaultheight,
    bar width=7pt,
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    enlarge y limits=upper,
    xtick=data,     
    xticklabels={2013,2014,2015,2016,2017},
    ymin=0
]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {
        (1,7)(2,5)(3,5)(4,7)(5,2)(6,4)(7,12)(8,0)(9,2)(10,6)(11,0)(12,0)(13,0)(14,2)(15,5)(16,0)(17,2)(18,6)(19,1)(20,0)(21,8)(22,10)(23,2)(24,21)(25,9)(26,4)(27,6)(28,32)(29,10)(30,10)(31,24)(32,44)(33,51)(34,43)(35,29)(36,39)(37,27)(38,12)(39,0)(40,9)(41,21)(42,7)(43,32)(44,1)(45,14)(46,22)(47,1)(48,23)(49,3)(50,13)(51,15)(52,23)(53,5)(54,16)(55,9)(56,28)(57,2)(58,26)(59,10)(60,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces:

[image: messed up grid labels and grid]

I tried some hacky solution using lots of empty commas and hand-drawn lines to somehow get what I want.

[image: target]

But as you can see, centering labels is hard (and will probably fail for other ranges). So do you have an idea how to:

- create a vertical grid by years (each 12th entry)
- use centered label for the year
- bonus: remove the other (small) grid dashes for the x-axis on the top and bottom (optional!)

Answer (score 3):

One option might be to add a tick every 6, 18, etc. month, with

```
xtick={6,18,...,60},
```

and then calculate a new value to use for the labels with

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{(\tick-6)/12+2013}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
```

Note `xticklabel` instead of `xticklabels`. This lets you define a pattern for the ticklabels, based on the data value for the ticks, which is given by `\tick`. Subtracting six and dividing by twelve gives you years from start, add 2013 to get the correct year.

In addition, add

```
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
```

to remove the comma used to separate the thousands by default.

Two other small changes:

- `bar width=1` makes each bar one axis unit wide (i.e. one month). This requires you to enable `compat=1.7` or a higher version number. I added 1.18 in the example below, because that is the version I have installed, if you have some older version of the package you have to modify that.
- `enlarge x limits={abs=0.5}` adds 0.5 at each end of the axis, so that the bars at the end are inside the axis.

[image: output of ode]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width=1.1\textwidth,
    height=\axisdefaultheight,
    bar width=1, % with compat=1.7 or newer, a number without a unit is interpreted as axis units
    grid=both,
    enlarge y limits=upper,
    xtick={6,18,...,60},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{(\tick-6)/12+2013}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ymin=0,
    enlarge x limits={abs=0.5}
]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=gray] coordinates {
        (1,7)(2,5)(3,5)(4,7)(5,2)(6,4)(7,12)(8,0)(9,2)(10,6)(11,0)(12,0)(13,0)(14,2)(15,5)(16,0)(17,2)(18,6)(19,1)(20,0)(21,8)(22,10)(23,2)(24,21)(25,9)(26,4)(27,6)(28,32)(29,10)(30,10)(31,24)(32,44)(33,51)(34,43)(35,29)(36,39)(37,27)(38,12)(39,0)(40,9)(41,21)(42,7)(43,32)(44,1)(45,14)(46,22)(47,1)(48,23)(49,3)(50,13)(51,15)(52,23)(53,5)(54,16)(55,9)(56,28)(57,2)(58,26)(59,10)(60,0)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```